# Migrate Magento 1.4 to 2.x

Tags: magento2-migration-tool, magento-1.4

I have inherited a Magento CE 1.4 shop that obviously needs upgrading. Preferrably I'd want to migrate straight to Magento CE 2 to be the most future proof. I am aware that this is not supported by [official guide](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/bk-migration-guide.html), and I'll most likely need to do most of the stuff manually.

The shop has around 4,000 SKUs, so it's not huge, but it's not small either, so I'd love some guidance on how to keep the amount of pain as small as possible - being fully aware that it will likely be painful nonetheless...

The whole thing gets further complicated by the fact that the current shop is in a shared hosting environment, so anything that needs SSH access to the current shop is out of the question.

The most important factors for me are:

**1) Products and product attributes**

I'd really need these transferred. I know I can do an export of products to CSV from the Magento 1.4 shop.

- Is the CSV produced compatible with the 2.x importer?
- Is there a way to get a similar export/import for attributes?

**2) Customers**

Basically the same as above. Can the exported data be imported to a 2.x shop?

I'm alright if I need to set up categories and the CMS completely manually, and need to do any custom features manually as well.

Is there any other guidance you can give me to avoid the worst headaches and nervous break downs during this migration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just migrated one 1.4.1.1 shop to 2.1.2   ... it is not problem, you have to upgrade site at least to 1.6 (i upgraded to 1.9.3.1) and then use magento migrate tool. If your database is ok (mine wasn't) everything should be over in one day it is not complicated.

CSVs are not compatible, and if you have configurable products it is best to forget that.

If you don't have ssh, you can rent some cloud server like DO and migrate everything there and just upload migrated version on your server, but you will need ssh access so maybe it is time to consider move to VPS or dedicated server.

Comment: Thanks. That's super helpful. I had thought about doing something like this, but just to make my life harder, the previous devs changed plenty of core files. So, even an upgrade to 1.x seems risky. I might end up exporting the most important data into a new store based on 1.9, and then migrate that one to 2.x. I'll need loads of coffee I think ....

Answer (score 0):

nanos, There few thing , you want to info

### Require SSh

Magento2 **most of things** are depends on **Shell basic**.SO, if you don't have any shell *access/ssh access* then it **cannot possible to work at Magento2**

### Structure:

Magento2 and magento1 Structure, **are different**,Magento2 using **Model, View, ViewModel (MVVM) system.** and magento1 **using MVC**.

### Migration of Data:

Magento2 have [migration tool](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-tool-install.html) bu which database of magento1 , can be convert to Magento2.All **data from magento1 goes to magento 2**.

https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool/blob/master/README.md

### Migration of Code:

Also magento2 have provide [code migration tool](https://github.com/magento/code-migration), That convert Magento1X

- Module directory structure
- Layout XML files
- Config XML files
- PHP files

to magento 2 version. **Module/themes are not properly convert at Magento2 work stage**. For that case, you need M**agento2 Expert which will make all thing working**

### Conclusion:

You must have

- ssh access
- Must have magento2 expert

For convert Magento1 to magento 2

---

Comment: Thanks Amit. Yes, I think most of what you said I was aware of. I will have ssh access to the new magento 2 server, for sure. The tools you mentioned aren't compatible with version 1.4 though, so I will likely (unless someone comes around to rescue me) basically have to install a new shop, and export/import all the data. I'm not even going to try to migrate the PHP stuff - so few customization and so poorly written that its faster to start from scratch. Basically my main questions probably are: is the 1.4 exporter compatible with the 2.x importer? And can I ex-/import product attributes?